# SQL: Calculating Percent Completion of specific Month based on Day

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How can I calculate the percent completion of a specific month based on the day?
E.g. Aug 18, 2021 is 18/31 complete (approx) - what SQL could be used here?

(Asking mostly as I've found similar answers for Excel, just making a specific post for SQL)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be quick & dirty, but it appears to work:

```
SELECT (CAST(DAY(GETDATE()) AS FLOAT)/DAY(EOMONTH(GETDATE(),0)))
```

Cast/convert your datatypes as needed. `GETDATE()` can be replaced with the date of your choosing.

Comment: You don't want to be using a float for a decimal value.

Comment: @DaleK No particular reason why you shouldn't: 18 / 31 = 0.58064516129 which isn't a nice decimal anyway

Answer (score 1):

```
select Day(GetDate())*1.0 / Day(EOMonth(GetDate())) * 100
```

Multiply by decimal value for implicit cast to decimal division.